# Different branches do not contribute equally in a deep neural network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

Assume we have a neural network that gets two inputs. the first input is location and size of a object and the second one is an image of the object. the location and size go through an MLP that map 4 dimensional input to 512 dimensional vector and the image go through ResNet34 which gives us a 512 dimensional vector that describes appearance of the object. After obtaining them position vector and appearance vector are summed to obtain a singular vector. Then the vector goes through the rest of the network.

After training the network, I  gained a bad accuracy. I analyzed what happens in the network, and I realized that position vector is not treated similarly as appearance vector and appearance branch has more weight in calculations.

I want my appearance and position features have the same impact. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of summing your image vector with the vector from the additional features, I would suggest concatenating them - so you end up with a 1024 dimensional vector. Then the layers that come after this concatenation can determine the relative impact of the features through your loss function.

This should allow the model to rely more heavily on whatever features result in the lowest loss.